# numpy.savetxt list of integers with right alignment?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to write a list of integers to a file in Python using `numpy.savetxt`. I want the integers to be right-aligned (padded with spaces on the left). How can I specify that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `fmt` argument.  For example, `fmt='%10i'` (or `fmt='%10d'`) will write the integers right-aligned in a field of width 10.

Comment: Remember they are integers.

Comment: Well, this just did it for me: `fmt='%10i`. Just edit the `d` so I can accept this answer.

Comment: Sure thing, but `d` should be equivalent to `i`--see the table at https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations